# ProgressDialog in AsyncTask dismiss not working

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an android-application with Service-classes wo communicate with a RestWebService.
The Methods of the Service-classes use AsyncTasks. I want to show a ProgressDialog during the execution of the AsyncTask. Therefore I have a private field

```
public final class UserService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = UserService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static UserService instance = null;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public static UserService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UserService();
        }

        return instance;
    }
...
```

}

It is instanced in the method showProgressDialog(Context ctx):

```
private ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Context ctx) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();
    return progressDialog;
}
```

I call this method on onPreExecute of my AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = showProgressDialog(ctx);
}
```

And try to close it in onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse<User> unused) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPostExecute");
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

I see, that the onPostExecute method is executed, because the of the Log command, but my ProgressDialog doesn't close.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Comment: are you displaying a progressdialog inside a service?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have initialized the progressdialog object in the constructor before doing progressdialog.show() in preExecute if your asynctask is an external class.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not showing** your `ProgressDialog` **correctly**.

Upon showing it, call:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

// store the reference, "this" is the Context
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "title...", "message...");
```

upon hiding, **use the stored reference**:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: What is wrong with the OP's style of showing and dismissing?